# Which command is correct, if i want to use a gcp service account to perform glcoud command local

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I need to local in cmd do use some gcloud commands and i need to be authenticated as a Service-Acocunt, the json-key-file of that service account is saved in my local folder. And I am not clear:

- what is the difference between the 3 commands below?
- the 3 commands which one has more power and can overwirte the others?
- for my purpose, which one should i use?

**1.**

**gcloud auth default-application login**

//as i know, this one is NOT the same as "glcoud auth login",
but what is the difference?

When should i use this?

I know after this command, i will get this json file in my folder C:\Users<MyUserName>\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_creidentials.json

What does ADC (Application Default Credetial) mean?

Which Setting can overwrite this setting?

**2.**

**set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PATH}/${SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY-FILE-NAME}.json**

// if i only do command 3, i guess i do not have to use this command 2? What is the difference between command 2 and command 3? Which one has more power?

**3.**

**gcloud auth activate-service-account "${SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL}" --key-file=${PATH}/${SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY-FILE-NAME}.json --project=${PROJECT_ID}**

**gcloud config set account ${SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL}**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can, you should avoid to use service account key file. it's a security bad practice and can create issues in your project.

[image]

I strongly recommend to avoid the option 2 and 3 for that reason.

The option 1 is great but with a problem: you use your own account, and thus your own permission. Not the permission of a service account.

If you want to use the service account permission, you can impersonate the service account like that

```
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<Service account email>
```

*Note that you made a mistake in the command `gcloud auth default-application login` you inverted default and application*

To complete this command, you, your user account, must have the role "service account token creator" on the service account (or on the project/folder/organisation which contains it)

---

That being said, let me explain the ADC mechanism. The client library are built to automatically discover the current runtime environment credential and perform tests in [that order](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#search_order):

- Check if the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set. (your option 2 has the highest precedence)
- Check the well known location, the place where the `gcloud auth` store the credential files on Linux and Windows
- Check if the metadata server is deployed on the runtime environment; That metadata server is always deployed with any Google Cloud services, on Google Cloud. It provide credential when required

---

A word about your option 3. In fact, option 1 and 2 set credential for the application-default context, means when you run code and the client libraries looks for credentials in the runtime environment.

The option 3 set the service account credentials with the service account key file for the gcloud CLI. Not the your own code. It's a different scope.